# Is it possible to set terminal to open at login on a mac?

Tags: macos, terminal.app

After taking a computer architecture class, I noticed I've been using my trackpad less and less and instead relying more on keyboard input to open, edit, create files, folders etc. But I have to deliberately open Terminal after login. Is there a way to automate opening the app?

Comment: Consider using http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Startup Item.

1. Go to System Preferences -> Users & Groups.
2. Select your user and click on the "Login Items" tab.
3. Press the + button and browse to the application you want to load.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up Login or Startup items

- Log in as the user who wishes to have a login item or as an admin
  user.
- Choose System Preferences from the Apple menu.
- Choose Accounts from the View menu.
- Click the name of the user.
- Mac OS X 10.3.x: Click the Startup Items button.
- Mac OS X 10.4 or later: Click the Login Items button.
- Click the "Add {+}" button.

The item you selected will automatically open the next time you log in.

Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2602

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be hardcore about it, logging in as ">console" from the login window (no password) will enter a special Terminal-only mode.